# Setting a cookie from url

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

When someone goes onto the website with this on the end of the url: /?utm_source=google I am trying to set a cookie and add a class to the body

At the moment it doesnt seem to be working correctly and it adds the class onto the body if you just go straight to the homepage

I am using the jquery cookie plugin

Don't suppose if anyone knows what I am doing wrong please, or a better way of doing it?

```
  var url = "(location.href.match(/utm\_source\=google/ig))";

  $.cookie("url", url, { expires:7, path: '/' });

 if ($.cookie("url")) {
    $('body').addClass('test');
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i got it working like so:

```
var url = "(location.href.match(/utm\_source\=google/ig))";

   if (location.href.match(/utm\_source\=google/ig)){
     $('body').addClass('test');
     $.cookie('number', 'url');

  }

    if ($.cookie('number')) {
         $('body').addClass('test');
    }
```